# Select most frequently visited location within a delta using Mysql Mysiam table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, geolocation

I am a newbie to geolocation handling in mysql. I am trying to identify the most frequently visited location. The database is mysql and the table uses Mysiam Engine and I have some geoindexing on the location. Here is table header.

|  id  |  user_id  |   datetime   | location   |

The location is represented by a geometry point of lat and long that I can get from GPS readings. Due to errors and noise in the GPS measurements, a 20 meter radius from any point is considered still the same point.  So, I would like to find the most frequently visited area based on a point and a radius. I though of using the MBR but it is not clear to me how to do the select statement

```
SELECT location FROM locations WHERE user_id = 2 AND  ...;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes a relatively straightforward solution if you are willing to accept a *square* of 20m side length (not a radius of 20m). Algorithm:

1. Separate your GPS data into lat and long coordinates (using, e.g., modulo `MOD` and integer-division `DIV` operations if the data is in integer format, or `SUBSTRING` for `VARCHAR`).
2. Find the equivalent of 20m in GPS lat and long coordinates. Call this value `0.5*length_unit`.
3. Set up a 2D-grid in mind with point distance `length_unit` in both directions. Round any lat and long coordinate to the next gridpoint (divide both coordinates by `length_unit`, then use the normal `ROUND` function. At this point, you arrived at a table with columns `| id | user_id | datetime | location |`, in which the entries in `location` are standardized, i.e. rounded to gridpoints.
4. Finally, you can use "normal" grouping functionality to obtain your result.

---

Here is a possible implementation to give you the idea (which, however, is untested and probably won't work like this):

```
SELECT lat*length_unit, long*length_unit, COUNT(*) AS number_of_visits
FROM
      (SELECT user_id
            , datetime
            //here you have to figure it out by yourself
            , ROUND(CONVERT(SUBSTRING(location,1,3),INTEGER) / length_unit) AS lat
            , ROUND(CONVERT(SUBSTRING(location,5,3),INTEGER) / length_unit) AS long
            FROM your_table
      )
WHERE datetime BETWEEN first_date AND second_date
GROUP BY lat, long
```

The main work is done in the following line, which needs to be adjusted by you (similarly for `long`):

```
ROUND(CONVERT(SUBSTRING(location,1,3),INTEGER) / (2*length_unit)) AS lat
```

Here, I have assumed that the GPS coordinates are given as a VARCHAR of length 7 (something like `123'456`). This string is split into lat/long, then converted to an integer and divided by `length_unit`. This you get a number like 34.723, which in the next step is rounded to 35. This means, you are at point 35 of your grid.

Finally, the number of visitors in a given time-interval is counted for each gridpoint, i.e., it is summed over each user (note this does include users which have been at one location more than a single time).

Please comment if you encounter problems in your implemenatation.